# Gaining intuition for a property of linear functions: why is $f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b) \equiv (1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda f(b)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, intuition

I am told that if we have some linear function $f$ defined over an interval $[a,b]$, then *the fact that $f$ is linear implies that*, for all $\lambda$ between 0 & 1 exclusive, the following property holds:
$$f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b) \equiv (1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda f(b)$$

Why is this the case? How can I see that the two expressions are equivalent to each other? My issue isn't in understanding what's being said here, but rather in *understanding why it's true*.

For context, I am trying to understand the definition of concave & convex functions, and this property is given as a minor step in the build up towards the definition, with no further elaboration.

EDIT: In the answer below I am told that this property is taken as *the definition* of a linear function.. but in the resource I'm using, it tells me that it is *due to $f$ being a linear function* that this property holds, so I feel quite confused.

Wouldn't it be possible to show that this property is implied by a more immediately intuitive definition?
Am I thinking about this in the wrong way? How should I view this property/definition?

Any help in clearing up my confusion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The definition of "f is linear" is: $\forall a, \forall b, f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, and $\forall \lambda, \forall a, f(\lambda a) = \lambda f(a)$. $f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b) \equiv (1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda f(b)$ is a consequence, not an equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Equivalently, for all values of $a$ and $b$ we have
> $$f\left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right) = (1 − \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) \qquad\text{for all } \lambda \in (0, 1)$$
>
> That is, a function is both concave and convex if and only if it is linear (or, more properly, affine), taking the form $f(x) = \alpha + \beta x$ for all $x$, for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Using "linear" for "affine", as the text does, the "*if and only if*" follows by double implication.

- If $f(x) = \alpha + \beta x$, then $f\left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right) = (1 − \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b)$ follows for all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$:
  $$
  \require{cancel}
  \begin{align}
  f\left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right) &= \alpha + \beta \left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right)
  \\ &= \alpha \cdot \left(\color{red}{(1-\lambda)} + \color{blue}{\lambda}\right) + \color{red}{\beta \cdot (1-\lambda) a} + \color{blue}{\beta \cdot \lambda b}
  \\ &= \color{red}{(1-\lambda)\cdot(\underbrace{\alpha + \beta a}_{\color{black}{=\,f(a)}})} + \color{blue}{\lambda (\underbrace{\alpha + \beta b}_{\color{black}{=\,f(b)}})}
  \\ &= (1-\lambda) f(a) + \lambda f(b)
  \end{align}
  $$
- If $f\left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right) = (1 − \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b)$ for all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$, then $f(x) = \alpha + \beta x$ follows for all $x \in [a,b]$. Let $\lambda = \frac{x-a}{b-a} \iff x = (1-\lambda)a + \lambda b$, then:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  f(x) = f\left((1−\lambda)a + \lambda b\right) &= (1 − \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b)
  \\ &= \left(1 - \frac{x-a}{b-a}\right) f(a) + \frac{x-a}{b-a} f(b)
  \\ &= \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a) + \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)
  \\ &= \underbrace{\frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{b-a}}_{=\,\alpha} + \underbrace{\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}_{=\,\beta}\,x
  \\ &= \alpha + \beta x
  \end{align}
  $$

> The fact that $h_{a,b}$ is linear means that
> $$h_{a,b}\left((1 − \lambda)a + \lambda b\right) = (1 − \lambda)h_{a,b}(a) + \lambda h_{a,b}(b)$$
> for any value of $\lambda$ with $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.

This is precisely the "*if*" part proved at the previous step, just with $h_{a,b}$ instead of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference for this, especially since you're about to cover convexity/concavity, is to think of

$$(1-\lambda) a + \lambda b$$

as being $(100\cdot \lambda)\%$ of the way from $a$ to $b$, and likewise for the outputs $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. This is justified as the standard parameterization of the line segment from $a$ to $b$ is given by the above expression with $\lambda \in [0,1]$, and most famously with $\lambda = \frac 1 2$ (giving you the midpoint). (You can play with this in a demo [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/udzouzzd44), working in two dimensions; the only difference is that, in higher dimensions, we apply the parameterization to each direction.)

What linearity means for  functions, then, is that being $(100\cdot \lambda)\%$ of the way from $a$ to $b$, means that the output $f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b)$ is likewise $(100\cdot\lambda)\%$ of the way between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

You can likewise think of linear functions, under your definition, as being those functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that, whenever $x<y$ and $x,y \in [a,b]$, then the line segment from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$ coincides with the graph of $f$. (For convex functions, that line segment will always lie on or above the graph, and for convex functions it will lie below.) Perhaps [this demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5zl2vjbeoj) will prove useful for that; as examples of each type of function:

- Linear: $f(x)=ax$ for any constant $a$
- Convex: $f(x)=x^2$, $f(x) = a^x$ for $a>0$
- Concave: $f(x)=\sqrt x$, $f(x) = \ln(x)$

If you remember your Calculus I material, the notion of "convex" here generalizes that of "concave up" functions (where you had $f'' > 0$), and "concave" functions are those that were "concave down" (where you had $f''<0$).

Comment: "being $(100\cdot\lambda)\%$ of the way from $a$ to $b$ means that the output $f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b)$ is likewise $(100\cdot\lambda)\%$ of the way between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$" Why is this the case? How does this follow from the definition of linearity? 
What exactly is the definition of a linear function and how can I see that the definition implies this property?

Comment: The definition in the context you're concerned about is: $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is ***linear*** if

$$\forall x,y \in [a,b], \; \forall \lambda \in [0,1], \text{ we have } f \Big( (1-\lambda) x + \lambda y \Big) = (1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda f(y)$$

If you can accept that $(1-\lambda) x + \lambda y$ is $(\lambda \cdot 100)\%$ of the way between $x$ and $y$, then the claim for the outputs follows by the definition above.

Comment: So this "property" of linear functions is actually just the definition of a linear function? I thought that a function is defined as linear if it has a constant rate of change, and I thought that this "property" would somehow be implied by such a definition. It feels kind of unsatisfactory to just take this "property" as the definition.. why is this the definition? Am I overthinking something obvious?

Comment: This is the resource I'm using to learn about concavity & convexity: https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cv1/t what confuses me is the part where the author says that "The fact that $h_{a,b}$ is linear means that $h_{a,b}((1-\lambda)a+ \lambda b)=(1-\lambda)h_{a,b}(a)+\lambda h_{a,b}(b)$" Why does $h_{a,b}$ being linear imply the equivalence?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui I posted a purely algebraic derivation for reference, but you should really read *this* answer here and play with the linked demos until you become comfortable with each step along the way, because the geometric insight is most valuable.

Comment: @Mahdi Rkkioui No, while the identity $\ f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda b)=$$\, (1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda(b))\  $ *does follow from* the linearity of $\ f\ $, it is *not equivalent to it*,  and is *not*  its definition.  To be linear, $\ f\ $ must satisfy the identity$$f(\mu x + \lambda y)=\mu f(x)+\lambda f(y)$$ for *all* $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ and *all* scalars $\ \mu,\lambda\ $, not merely for just $\  x=a,$$\,y=b,$$\,0\le\lambda\le1 \ $ and $\ \mu=1-\lambda\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera OP's textbook (linked in a previous comment) uses "linear" for "affine" in this context. The relevant paragraph is copied in full in my post. The first identity you quote is in fact equivalent to $f$ being affine.